# Setinterval won't work with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello I'm Coding a plug in for j Query but the problem i have to use the function $.now()
anyway when i use it with alert() it works perfectly, but when i put it in a code it doesn't show anything and the text() works in plug-in also but the only problem is when i use the function set interval now thing shows up i have tried this code:

```
setInterval(function(){

this.text($.now());

},1000);
```

it doesn't work but when i use alert it works so what i have to do?

Comment: what exact you need to do? can you give some more clarification about **this.text**

Comment: How "this" is declared here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You lose the context when inside the setinterval call back function. You can do this way.

```
//.. some event

var $this = $(this);

setInterval(function(){
   $this.text($.now());
},1000); 

//.. code follows
```

Or with **[$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)** you can set the context.

```
setInterval($.proxy(function(){
   $(this).text($.now());
},this),1000);
```

Or with Ecmascript 5 **[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** (*Support for IE8 and below only through the shim mentioned in the document* )

```
setInterval((function(){
   $(this).text($.now());
}).bind(this),1000);
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eB5vB/)** with all the three options

Comment: thank you it works but can you tell me why when i used it in normal programming jquery it works but when i using in plugin it lose the context?

Comment: @WalidNaceri That is because the callback function for the setInterval will point to the global context, like a window context or if in node it will be global context. Hence we are binding the context here.

Answer (score 0):

What does this refer to? Suggest you put the actual selector instead of this. Inside a function, the value of this can vary

```
var obj = $(".text");
setInterval(function(){
    obj.text($.now());
},1000);
```

obj acts as a closure here